# Copying code from one project to another

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios7

I am having an issue where I am copying code from one project to another, completely separate projects.

The code still shows as being linked to the previous storyboard's file somehow.

[image]

Is there anyway to remove these links? Without re-creating all the code manually

Comment: How do you mean... copying?  How are you copying it?  Are you copy&pasting the text in a newly created class?  Are you copy&pasting via finder?

Comment: copy&paste into a newly created class. So its actually a duplicate name of the class in this case and it is created as standard then the code replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode, go into your Developer folder, go to Xcode, Derived Data, then move everything in there to the trash. If you can't find your Developer folder, look in your Library.